# Integral of $\frac{1}{x}\ln\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}-x}+\frac{1}{2}\right)$

Tags: integration

As the title says, I am attempting to find the indefinite integral of $\frac{1}{x}\ln\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}-x}+\frac{1}{2}\right)$. Setting $x=\frac{1}{4}\cos^2\theta$ yields $\int(2\tan\theta\ln2-2\tan\theta\ln(1+\sin\theta)\ d\theta),$ and $u=\sin\theta$ on the second term of this yields $\int\frac{u\ln(u+1)}{1-u^2}\ d\theta,$ but I'm not quite sure how to move forward from here.

Comment: According with Mathematica it seems that the integration requires the  polylogarithm function $Li_2[x]$

Comment: @LucaGoldoniPh.D. I'd be curious to know how to get to that. I'm proving $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{2n}{n}\cdot\frac{1}{4^n(n+1)^3}=4\ln^22-8\ln2-\dfrac{\pi^2}{3}+8$, and this integral has come up.

Comment: If you integrate between $0$ and $\frac 14$, the integral is $\log ^2(2)-\frac{\pi ^2}{12}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$I=\int\frac{1}{x}\ln\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}-x}+\frac{1}{2}\right)\,dx$$

Start with
$$u=\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}-x}+\frac{1}{2}\implies x=u-u^2\implies dx=(1-2u)\,du$$ This makes
$$I=\int \frac{(1-2 u) \log (u)}{u-u^2}\,du$$ Use partial fraction decomposition for $\frac{(1-2 u) }{u-u^2}$ to get
$$I=\int \frac{ \log (u)}{u}\,du+\int \frac{ \log (u)}{u-1}\,du$$ The first integral is simple
$$\int \frac{ \log (u)}{u}\,du=\frac{1}{2}\log ^2(u)$$ For the second one, let $u=v+1$
$$\int \frac{ \log (u)}{u-1}\,du=\int \frac{ \log (v+1)}{v}\,dv=-\text{Li}_2(-v)=-\text{Li}_2(1-u)$$ where appears the polylogarithm function.

So
$$I=\frac{1}{2}\log ^2(u)-\text{Li}_2(1-u)+C \qquad \text{where}\qquad u=\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}-x}+\frac{1}{2}$$

**Edit**

I think that I saw the connection with the summation you put in comments.

Consider
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{2n}{n}\frac{x^n}{4^n(n+1)^3}=\, _4F_3\left(\frac{1}{2},1,1,1;2,2,2;x\right)$$ Expanded, this is
$$-\frac{4 \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{1-x}}{2}\right)}{x}-\frac{8
   \sqrt{1-x}}{x}+\frac{8}{x}+\frac{2 \left(\log \left(\sqrt{1-x}+1\right)-\log
   (2)\right)^2}{x}+\frac{8 \left(\log \left(\sqrt{1-x}+1\right)-\log (2)\right)}{x}$$

Comment: $+C$, but otherwise well done.